# How Do I Inactivate Autoplay?

Tags: javascript, html, deezer

I've tried to embed a radio in a blog of mine, but despite having autoplay turned off it goes on automatically after time I open the page. How do I sort this out? I have already tried deleted the autoplay message, but that didn't work either. Could you please fix this or make the code correctly written so I have autoplay turned off? Here's the code right now:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="80" scrolling="no" src="http://www.deezer.com/plugins/player?autoplay=false&amp;playlist=false&amp;width=450&amp;height=80&amp;cover=false&amp;type=radio&amp;id=artist-2179&amp;title=&amp;app_id=undefined" width="470"></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you sure they did not covered it all in their API? http://developers.deezer.com/login?redirect=/api

Comment: Nothing I can find anyway. :/ But it's possible I've missed something, just not sure what. Consider they had that box to check or uncheck, it would had more sense if just unchecking it would have prevented the player from going off.